# JAVAH не может найти требуемый класс

Tags: android-ndk, android, java

При запуске `javah -jni` команда наотрез отказывается находить нужный класс:

> $PROJECT_DIRECTORY/bin$
> **javah -jni**
> **bt.nativeclient.BtnativeActivity**
>
> error: cannot access
> bt.nativeclient.BtnativeActivity class
> file for
> bt.nativeclient.BtnativeActivity not
> found javadoc: error - Class
> bt.nativeclient.BtnativeActivity not
> found. Error: No classes were
> specified on the command line.  Try
> -help

Мой класс java имеет аддрес: $PROJECT_DIRECTORY/src/**bt/nativeclient/BtnativeActivity.java** и имеет вид:

```
package bt.nativeclient;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class **BtnativeActivity** extends Activity   { 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText( stringFromJNI() );
        setContentView(tv);
    }

    public native String stringFromJNI();

    static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }  
}
```

Я пробовал запускать **javah** из: `$PROJECT_DIRECTORY`/**bin**, `$PROJECT_DIRECTORY`/**src**, просто из `$PROJECT_DIRECTORY`. Я пробовал специфицировать путь для поиска класса через опцию `-classpath`:

```
$PROJECT_DIRECTORY/src javah -classpath :. bt.nativeclient.BtnativeActivity
```

Более того, если включить опцию `-verbose` команда javah говорит, что она исказала мой класс в той директории, где этот самый класс она должна была найти:

> `$PROJECT_DIRECTORY
> **javah -verbose -classpath :./src -jni**
> **bt.nativeclient.BtnativeActivity** error: cannot access
> bt.nativeclient.BtnativeActivity class
> file for
> bt.nativeclient.BtnativeActivity not
> found javadoc: error - Class
> bt.nativeclient.BtnativeActivity not
> found. [ **Search Path**:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/netx.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rhino.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/classes/:**./src**
> ]`

Я перепробовал все возможные комбинации, но не нашел решения.
Мне кажется, я упустил какую-то маленькую деталь по своей неопытности, может кто-нибуть помочь мне, пожалуйста?

Comment: Проверьте права доступа к своему каталогу с исходниками

Comment: @Алексей Выхристюк, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо указывать пусть к .class файлу, они не в bin а в bin\classes. Класспас указывает не на ваш исходних а на дополнительные библиотеки, если их нет, то просто из папки bin\classes вызовите команду

```
>javah <пакет>.<пакет>.<класс>
```

Должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень помогли.